# cannot pass the obj-c class obj to another view

Tags: iphone, objective-c, oop, object

I have 3 classes

First -> MainViewController:

```
@interface MainViewController : UIViewController {
    UtilityBadah *utility;

    }
    @property (strong, nonatomic) NSManagedObjectContext *managedObjectContext;
    - (IBAction)option;
    @end

    @implementation MainViewController
    @synthesize managedObjectContext = _managedObjectContext;
    (IBAction)option{
    UtilityBadah *util = [[UtilityBadah alloc] initWithContext:_managedObjectContext];
    OptionController *ovc = [[OptionController alloc] init];
    ovc.util = util;
    ovc.managedObjectContext = _managedObjectContext;    
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:ovc animated:YES];
    [util release];
    [ovc release];
    }

    @end
```

Second -> UtilityBadah:

```
@interface UtilityBadah : NSObject {

NSManagedObjectContext *managedObjectContext;
NSString *kitab;
NSString *lagu;
NSString *font;
NSString *sizefont;
}
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSManagedObjectContext *managedObjectContext;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString *kitab;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString *lagu;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString *font;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString *sizefont;
(id) initWithContext: (NSManagedObjectContext *) context;
@end

@implementation UtilityBadah
@synthesize managedObjectContext;
@synthesize kitab;
@synthesize lagu;
@synthesize font;
@synthesize sizefont;

-(id) initWithContext: (NSManagedObjectContext *) context {
NSError *err;
NSFetchRequest *request = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
NSEntityDescription *enDesc = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"OptionDB" inManagedObjectContext:context];
[request setEntity:enDesc];
NSArray *arrData = [context executeFetchRequest:request error:&err];

for (OptionDB *data in arrData) {
lagu = data.lagu;
kitab = data.kitab;
font = data.font;
sizefont = data.sizefont;
}
return self;
}
```

Thrid -> OptionController:

```
@interface OptionController : UIViewController{

    NSManagedObjectContext *managedObjectContext;
    UtilityBadah *util;
}

@property (nonatomic, retain) NSManagedObjectContext *managedObjectContext;
@property (nonatomic, retain) UtilityBadah *util;
@end

(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView
         cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    bla..bla..

    NSLog(@"value is %@",self.util.kitab);
    cell.textLabel.text = [listData objectAtIndex:row];    
    return cell;
}
```

i wonder why this piece of code:

```
NSLog(@"value is %@",self.util.kitab);
```

cause an error "Receiced signa: "EXC_BAD_ACCESS" ?
i wonder ther somthing wrong the way i passed the UtilityBadah object from MainViewController to my OptionController.

Many thanks for any answer.

P.S what is wrong with my xcode 4.2 error information, why it always show "Program received signal: "EXC BAD ACCESS"? cant it be informative?

Comment: What happens if you try this:     NSLog(@"util is: %@", self.util);

Comment: well it wasnt error but it showed: 2012-02-03 20:12:12.137 iBadah[13981:207] util is: <UtilityBadah: 0x6d121d0>. i meant how can it access every property in UtilityBadah class?

Answer (score 1):

i think your init method is wrong, try assigning self to [super init] at the start, and doing all your set up after checking that self != nil. this is the basic form of an init:

```
- (id)init
{
    self = [super init];
    if (self)
        //do setup
    return self;
}
```

also, you are using a subclass of `NSObject` and associating a managed object context to it, you should look into core data in more detail, you should be using `NSManagedObject`s

Comment: i changed the my init method as u suggested, but still no luck. Anyway about nsmanageobject instead of nsmanageobjectcontext, can u gimme any good article bout this, so i can learn (less ppl talk about it in internet) ? tx

Comment: [this is the best place to start](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreData/cdProgrammingGuide.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30001200-SW1)

Answer (score 0):

The property name in the `OptionController` is `util` not `utility`

If you want to access the `utility` property in the `UtilityBadah` class you will have to do:

```
self.util.utility
```

Comment: sory Oscar, i used util not utility (my bad), just update the program

Comment: i meant, i used util and it was error. (it just typo when put it in this forum)

Answer (score 0):

In the `UtilityBadah` class, `initWithContext` method, change the `for` loop as following

```
for (OptionDB *data in arrData) {
  self.lagu = data.lagu;
  self.kitab = data.kitab;
  self.font = data.font;
  self.sizefont = data.sizefont;
}
```

In your case, the value is not retained since you have assigned without accessing through the property.

Comment: In that loop, only last data would be retained.

Comment: firstly i did in tat way, and yes this code -> self.lagu = data.lagu; cause error -> program received signal: SIGABRT

Answer (score 0):

You need to allocate those objects first. Here's how your initWithContext method should look like:

```
-(id) initWithContext: (NSManagedObjectContext *) context {
    self = [super init];
    if (self) {
        NSError *err;
        NSFetchRequest *request = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
        NSEntityDescription *enDesc = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"OptionDB" inManagedObjectContext:context];
        [request setEntity:enDesc];
        NSArray *arrData = [context executeFetchRequest:request error:&err];

        for (OptionDB *data in arrData) {
            self.lagu = [NSString stringWithString:data.lagu];
            self.kitab = [NSString stringWithString:data.kitab];
            self.font = [NSString stringWithString:data.font];
            self.sizefont = [NSString stringWithString:data.sizefont];
        }
    }
    return self;
}
```

Comment: this one ended with same result with Lanc answer's :(

Comment: What is the result? The SIGABRT?